# Expanding tuple into number repeated X times in a list (python)

Tags: python

This seems simple, but I can't figure it out. I have ten categories and scores assigned to each of them. In an intermediate step, I am storing results as ["score", repeats] pairs, as in:

```
[20,3]
[40,7]
[50,2]
```

...

What I want to do in the end is expand these pairs into repeats of numbers, then merge and average to get one score like this:

```
[20,20,20]
[40,40,40,40,40,40,40]
[50,50]
```

Merged:

```
[20,20,20,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,50,50]

sum([20,20,20,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,50,50],0.0)/12
```

Final result (average): 37

So how do I accomplish step #2, where I expand the scores X times for each pair? I could do this if they were strings, but there has to be a numeric way to do it.

Comment: For the general case of repeating `x[0]` `x[1]` times, you can use `itertools.repeat(*x)`.

Comment: @agf: That's a really obfuscated way of doing it, I wouldn't recommend it unless x[1] is really large and you want to avoid creating a list. Even then I'd write it as `itertools.repeat(x[0], x[1])`.

Comment: @interjay I don't see a problem with the `*x` syntax. Anyone used to Python knows what it means, and it allows automatic support for infinite repetition. There are also lots of times you don't need / want a list even if `x[1]` isn't large. It isn't the answer to this particular question, which is why I posted it as a comment, but it is useful for people looking to repeat an arbitrary object many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> a = [20,3]
>>> [a[0]] * a[1]
[20, 20, 20]
```

However, this step isn't really necessary. To get the weighted average, you can multiply the values by the weights, sum them, and then divide by the sum of the weights, such as:

```
float(20*3 + 40*7 + 50*2) / (3 + 7 + 2)
```

The conversion to float is done to avoid integer division in Python 2.

It can be written like this:

```
>>> xs = [[20,3], [40,7], [50,2]]
>>> float(sum(x[0] * x[1] for x in xs)) / sum(x[1] for x in xs)
36.666666666666664
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Not sure exactly why you need brackets around a[0] but it does the trick for me.

Comment: `a[0]` is just `20`, but what you want is a list containing a single item, that is: `[a[0]]` = `[20]` and therefore `[a[0]] * 3` is `[20, 20, 20]`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to expand the lists, it's as simple as:

```
x = [20, 3] # for example
# a list consisting of x[1] copies, of a list that contains only x[0]:
expanded = [x[0]] * x[1]
```

However, for the problem you've described, *you don't actually want or need to do that*. What you are really doing is calculating a [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average), where the second values are your weights.

To do this, we can just multiply the pairs together, add those results, and then divide by the sum of the weights:

```
values = [[20, 3], [40, 7], [50, 2]]
total = sum(x[0] * x[1] for x in values)
weight = sum(x[1] for x in values)
average = float(total) / weight
# Or, more directly:
average = float(sum(x[0] * x[1] for x in values)) / sum(x[1] for x in values)
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I bother writing full explanations for simple questions like this. It just leads to getting beaten to the punch by a couple of minutes and losing all the fame and glory :/

Comment: I thought the normal rep-whore method was to submit the absolute minimum to meet the length requirement; then edit it with your *real* answer.  Or at least a fast-but-still-meaningful answer.  Then lather, rinse, repeat as necessary to shape your answer into what you'd like.  Maybe your old-school answering technique is what is keeping you only in the top 3% of SO users, rather than in the top 1%. :P

Comment: LOL. I guess I'm not really in a position to complain :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to create the expanded list if you are just trying to get the average?

I suggest you do a weighted average, instead.

```
count = sum(k[1] for k in scores)  # this is the count of items
total = sum(k[0] * k[1] for k in scores)   # this is the sum of scores
out = total / count
```

Comment: I believe the first `sum` should be of `k[1]` not `k[0]`